# Memoization code in C++: why it doesn't work?

Tags: c++, memoization

I got [this example](http://slackito.com/2011/03/17/automatic-memoization-in-cplusplus0x/) about implementing generic memoization in C++. However, as someone made notice in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/g5j1a/automatic_memoization_in_c0x/c1l6amw) comment, the original code makes 2 lookups, while the code below makes only one.

The only problem is that there is an error at the second `return` that I don't understand.

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
std::function<ReturnType (Args...)> memoize(std::function<ReturnType (Args...)> func)
{
    std::map<std::tuple<Args...>, ReturnType> cache;
    return ([=](Args... args) mutable  {
            std::tuple<Args...> t(args...);
auto range = cache.equal_range(t);
if (range.first != range.second) return (*range.first).second;
return (*cache.insert(range.first, func(args...))).second;

    });
}
```

Compiler error:

```
 In instantiation of 'memoize(std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>)::<lambda(Args ...)> mutable [with ReturnType = int; Args = {int, int}]':
14:36:   required from 'struct memoize(std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>) [with ReturnType = int; Args = {int, int}]::<lambda(int, int)>'
16:6:   required from 'std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)> memoize(std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>) [with ReturnType = int; Args = {int, int}]'
34:56:   required from here
14:9: error: no matching function for call to 'std::map<std::tuple<int, int>, int, std::less<std::tuple<int, int> >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::tuple<int, int>, int> > >::insert(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::tuple<int, int>, int> >&, int)'
14:9: note: candidates are:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/map:61:0,
                 from 1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:629:7: note: std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator, bool> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(const value_type&) [with _Key = std::tuple<int, int>; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less<std::tuple<int, int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::tuple<int, int>, int> >; typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::tuple<int, int>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair<const std::tuple<int, int>, int>]
       insert(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:629:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:637:9: note: template<class _Pair, class> std::pair<typename std::_Rb_tree<_Key, std::pair<const _Key, _Tp>, std::_Select1st<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, _Compare, typename __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<_Alloc>::rebind<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >::other>::iterator, bool> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_Pair&&) [with _Pair = _Pair; <template-parameter-2-2> = <template-parameter-1-2>; _Key = std::tuple<int, int>; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less<std::tuple<int, int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::tuple<int, int>, int> >]
         insert(_Pair&& __x)
         ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:637:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
14:9: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/map:61:0,
                 from 1:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:650:7: note: void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >) [with _Key = std::tuple<int, int>; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less<std::tuple<int, int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::tuple<int, int>, int> >]
       insert(std::initializer_list<value_type> __list)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:650:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:679:7: note: std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, const value_type&) [with _Key = std::tuple<int, int>; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less<std::tuple<int, int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::tuple<int, int>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator = std::_Rb_tree_iterator<std::pair<const std::tuple<int, int>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator = std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::pair<const std::tuple<int, int>, int> >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::value_type = std::pair<const std::tuple<int, int>, int>]
       insert(const_iterator __position, const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:679:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from 'int' to 'const value_type& {aka const std::pair<const std::tuple<int, int>, int>&}'
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:690:9: note: template<class _Pair, class> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::iterator std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::const_iterator, _Pair&&) [with _Pair = _Pair; <template-parameter-2-2> = <template-parameter-1-2>; _Key = std::tuple<int, int>; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less<std::tuple<int, int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::tuple<int, int>, int> >]
         insert(const_iterator __position, _Pair&& __x)
         ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:690:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:686:32: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
       template<typename _Pair, typename = typename
                                ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/bits/stl_map.h:705:9: note: template<class _InputIterator> void std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::insert(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator; _Key = std::tuple<int, int>; _Tp = int; _Compare = std::less<std::tuple<int, int> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::tuple<int, int>, int> >]
         insert(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
         ^
```

Comment: If you have 2 questions, you should create two separate questions.

Comment: If you are getting a compiler error you should copy and paste that error into your question.

Comment: Flagged as (generously IMO) unclear-what-you're-asking, since you actively refuse to tell us what error you get, and you can't seem to decide between that unanswerable question or a totally different one. I mean, really - "I'll not report the error to keep the post clean" - are you kidding?

Comment: Sorry everybody, I've reported the compiler error.

Comment: Created new question for the second one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597697/unordered-map-why-range-operation-are-inefficient-and-this-is-case

Answer (score 2):

The error is inside your lambda:

```
auto range = cache.equal_range(t);
...
... cache.insert(range.first, func(args...)) ...
```

and is

```
14:9: error: no matching function for call to
'std::map<std::tuple<int, int>, int,...>
    ::insert(std::_Rb_tree_iterator<...>&, int)'
```

It's telling you that you're calling insert wrongly.

The range returned from [`equal_range`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/equal_range) is a pair of iterators - you need to dereference the first iterator *and* take the first (key) element, to get the key/value pair you want. That is, something like

```
cache.insert(range.first, make_pair(t, func(args...)))
```

---

In general, you can help yourself figure these errors out by:

- simplifying your code (these big compound statements mean lots of things are happening, and there's lots of potential errors, on a single line),
- by *reading the error message* carefully (it does list the column, and does say the problem is with `insert`,
- and if all else fails by reproducing the error in a minimal example (removing code unrelated to the error reduces the number of issues to consider).