# unordered_map : why range operation are inefficient, and this is case?

Tags: c++

I got [this example](http://slackito.com/2011/03/17/automatic-memoization-in-cplusplus0x/) about implementing generic memoization in C++. However, as someone made notice in this comment, the original code makes 2 lookups, while the code below makes only one.

```
template <typename ReturnType, typename... Args>
std::function<ReturnType (Args...)> memoize(std::function<ReturnType (Args...)> func)
{
    std::map<std::tuple<Args...>, ReturnType> cache;
    return ([=](Args... args) mutable  {
            std::tuple<Args...> t(args...);
auto range = cache.equal_range(t);
if (range.first != range.second) return (*range.first).second;
return (*cache.insert(range.first, func(args...))).second;

    });
}
```

Someone made notice that using unordered_map would have probably better performances. But I've [read](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/) that:

> they are generally less efficient for range iteration through a subset
>   of their elements. I don't understand why the range operation are less
>   efficient, and if the case above is one of these cases (since we use
>   range)?

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as someone made notice in this comment, the original code makes 2 lookups, while the code below makes only one

OK, so you're trying to use the hinted [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert) to avoid a redundant logarithmic-complexity search for the insertion point. You still have the same bug as the other question, and your code should probably look like:

```
cache.insert(range.first, std::make_pair(t, func(args...)));
//           ^hint        ^value_type
```

(this is overload #4 in the linked doc).

You could do without the first lookup entirely: `insert` simply returns an iterator to the existing element if the key is present, so you could write it with an optimistic insert - whether this is better depends on the cost of default-constructing and then assigning your ReturnType:

```
auto result = cache.insert(make_pair(t, ReturnType{}));
if (result.second) {
    // insertion succeeded so the value wasn't cached already
    result.first->second = func(args...);
}
return result.first->second;
```

> ... using unordered_map would have probably better performance ...

`std::map` find/insert scale with logarithmic complexity, and `std::unordered_map` scales with constant complexity. Which is actually better depends on how many entries you have, amongst other factors, and you need to profile to find out for sure.

> ... [unordered_map is] less efficient for range iteration ...

Well, you don't need range iteration at all if you avoid `equal_range`.

Look at the operations you actually use, and understand which data structure is a natural fit. For simple lookups and insertions, which are all you really need here, `unordered_map` is probably fine. `std::map` is better if you care about the relative ordering of keys, which you don't.

Both structures also have different requirements on the key: `map` needs an ordering (`operator<` or a custom comparator), while `unordered_map` needs a well-defined hash function and `operator==` or custom predicate.

For a start, I'm not sure `std::hash` supports `std::tuple`, so you might need to provide a custom hasher to use `unordered_map`.